# Mysql two column Find one data in Rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to try two joins but this is not going to work.
code in Codeginator.

```
$this->db->select('concat(firstName," ",lastName) as fullnameVisitor,users.firstName,visitorId,destinationId,count,activityStatus,created,updated');
    $this->db->from('interestedprofile');
    $this->db->join('users','users.userId=interestedprofile.visitorId','LEFT');
    $this->db->join('users','users.userId=interestedprofile.destinationId','LEFT');
    $this->db->join('interestedprofile','interestedprofile.destinationId=users.userId','LEFT');
    $this->db->order_by('created','desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

**User Table :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppM3s.png
**Interest Table :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbQIX.png

i have to find visitedid and destinationid users firstName and lastName in Users Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the Active Record fully to do the joins. You can use regular SQL. For example,

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->getResult('User') as $user)
{
    echo $user->name; // access attributes
    echo $user->reverseName(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
}
```

Comment: `code`select us1.firstName,us2.firstName from interestedprofile ip join users us1 on us1.userid = ip.visitorId join users us2 on us2.userId = ip.destinationId `code`  this query will be work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Work For me.

```
Select us1.firstName,us2.firstName from interestedprofile ip join users us1 on us1.userid = ip.visitorId join users us2 on us2.userId = ip.destinationId
```